# Value passing from one control to another class variable?

Tags: c#

I have one `textbox1` in form1,  I have another class called `ClassDemo()`, this class does not have a form. I have one method in this class, called `HelloWorld()` inside hello world I have one `string val` variable.

I want to pass the textbox1 value to ClassDemo's variable when the HelloWorld(), method is called.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why everyone begins with 'hi i'm new' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try multiple ways here.

1. **Make the method as parameterized method.** Put a `string` parameter inside the method declaration and then whenever you call that method, pass that `string` value that you want to pass.
2. **Store the `string` value in global variable or Session(only if needed).** This wasy, your value can flow across the application and can be accessed in any area wherever its needed.
3. **Pass by Value or Pass by reference.** You can opt for either one in C# to pass variables/values across connected areas.

Hope this clears the idea.

Comment: Ok good, can you give me an example of global variable or Session?

Comment: Pretty simple. You have to use `Session["someName"]=yourValue;`. For further details, you use this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx